# Call event when document is ready and document is resized

Tags: jquery

I use the following script to get the padding-top of a div. The div get's his padding-top from an hero-image height. The actuall script works great when the size is loaded but when i resize the browser window the padding top is not calculated again.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    /***** CONTENT-WRAPPER PADDING FRONTPAGE *****/
    var $banner = $(".front header img");
    $banner.on('load', function(){
        var bannerHeight = $(this).height();
        console.log(bannerHeight);
        $("#content-wrapper").css("padding-top", bannerHeight)
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
jQuery( window ).resize(function() {
  var bannerHeight = $(".front header img").height();
  console.log(bannerHeight);
  $("#content-wrapper").css("padding-top", bannerHeight)
});
```

Comment: Also, I think you should add "px" at the .css( function, like this:

$("#content-wrapper").css("padding-top", bannerHeight + "px");

Answer (score 0):

The [`resize()`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) event will fire every time the window is resized. Attach your handler to both events: `onReady` and `resize`:

```
function calcPaddingTop() {
    // your logic here
}

jQuery(document).ready(calcPaddingTop);
jQuery(window).resize(calcPaddingTop);
```

Comment: It is working on document.ready but not on resize. I dont know why. The solution from JC Herandez works. Do you know why?